# Best way to find non-randomness regions in these or similar count data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, count-data, hidden-markov-model, randomness

Let say I have data in a shape:
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,....]  - so mainly zeros....
However I know how long is my 'signal' and how many counts are they.

- Is it possible to find **regions of non-randomness** in it?

I assume that in my signal counts are spread in both random and non-random fashion, and I would like to find only the last one.

- Can I do it with HMM?